# Integration and inverse of a function

Tags: integration, functions, inverse-function

It is given that $f(x) = \int_0^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^3}}dt$ and $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$, then what is the value of $\frac{(g(x))^2}{g''(x)}$?

$f'(x) = (1+x^3)^{-0.5}$

$∵ g(x) = f^{-1} (x)$
$⇒ g'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(x)} = \sqrt{1+x^3}$
$⇒ g''(x) = -\frac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{1+x^3}}$

I am unable to proceed further. How to find $g(x)$ ?

Comment: Note: $g'(y)=1/f'(x)$, but $y \ne x$.

Comment: Your derivative of $g$ doesn't follow like you have written. note that $$(f^{-1}(x))'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$

Comment: Thanks you @Bacon, I corrected my mistake and got the answer as 2